# Recommended registry key or value locations

Tags: .net, windows, registry

I will be writing some sensitive information into the registry under HKLM\Software and HKCU\Software. This information is managed by a shared/common library and is not specific to a particular application. Currently I am writing into a value that is located right under HKLM\Software and HKCU\Software.

Is creating a value under HKLM\Software and HKCU\Software acceptable(for app certification etc ...)? any reason why I should not write it there?

Answer (score 1):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` contains the majority of the **`configuration information for the software you have installed`** and for the Windows operating system itself.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` contains configuration information for **`Windows and software specific to the currently logged in user`**.

Its better to write it in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` since its specific to the currently logged in user.

Comment: @user2384219 If you find **any** of the answers useful please **upvote it** and if answer is correct then 
please **accept it** this will help to remove the question from the list of **unanswered list of question**